# How to attach the data of inner for loop to the data of outer for loop to generate a dropdown list in front end

Tags: javascript, css

How to attach the data of inner forloop to the data of outerfor loop to generate a dropdown list in front end.

I tried but i could generate only the list of data but dono how to attach the data of innerforloop to each outer forloop ,so onclick of each outer forloop i need to generate dropdown list which should contain details of outer forloop.

Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myData1(){
     var appname;
     var hostid;
     $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/ZabbixRestApi/webapi/users/host",
        datatype:"json",
        type:"GET",
        success: function(Data){
                 for(i=0;i<Data.length;i++){
                       $("#messages").append("<option value=\""+Data[i].hostid+"\">"+Data[i].host+"</option>");
                       hostid=Data[i].hostid;
                    change4(hostid,function(data)
                    {
                        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                      {
                           $("#dropdown").append("<option value=\""+data[i].applicationid+"\">"+data[i].name+"</option>");
                      } 
                       }); 
                     for(i=0;i<appname.length;i++)
                        {
                    ("#appname").append("<option value=\""+appname[i].hostid+"\">"+appname[i].name+"</option>");
                        }  
                    }
                   },
    error: function(){
                alert("failure");
       }
    });

 }  
function change4(hostid,callback){

     $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/ZabbixRestApi/webapi/users/appiget/"+hostid,
        datatype:"json",
        type:"GET",
        success: function(data)
          {
            callback(data);
          },
        error: function(){
                alert("failure");
        }
    });
   }  

</script>
</head>
<body onload = "myData1()">

 <select id="messages">
    <option>Host Name</option>
    </select> 

<div id="dropdown"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... What is the problem? The language used in this question makes it difficult to understand.

Comment: Hi ,I want to generate a dropdown list ..that is data coming from inner for loop need to be attached to outer for loop.

Comment: I am getting data from both the loops. but stuck in generating dropdown  using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Closure`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

> `Inner function` remembers the environment in which it is created!

```js
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  $("#messages").append("<option value=\"" + Data[i].hostid + "\">" + Data[i].host + "</option>");
  var hostid = Data[i].hostid;
  (function(hostid) {
    change4(hostid, function(data) {
      console.log(hostid);
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#dropdown").append("<option value=\"" + data[i].applicationid + "\">" + data[i].name + "</option>");
      }
    });
    for (i = 0; i < appname.length; i++) {
      ("#appname").append("<option value=\"" + appname[i].hostid + "\">" + appname[i].name + "</option>");
    }
  })(hostid);
}
```

Comment: Hi ,I want to generate a dropdown list ..that is data coming from inner for loop need to be attached to outer for loop.

Comment: I am getting data from both the loops. but stuck in generating dropdown using javascript –